# Why the pr ogresschanged event is not firing?

Tags: c#

```
public void DownloadFile(string urlAddress, string location)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0 Chrome");
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler((sender, e) => Completed(sender, e, sw));
                webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler((sender, e) => ProgressChanged(sender, e, sw));

                Uri URL = new Uri(urlAddress);
                sw.Start();
                try
                {
                    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(URL, location);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

The progresschanged event

```
private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e, Stopwatch sw)
        {
          string itsnevergettinghereusingabreakpoint = "";
        }
```

it does getting to the completed event but never to the progresschanged event.

Comment: I can't spot any obvious errors in the code. are you sure you are debugging correctly? Also [consider using httpClient instead of webclient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/networking/6.0/webrequest-deprecated)

Comment: You are not awaiting `webClient.DownloadFileAsync()`, therefore the control flow will continue and exit the `using` before the download is complete. It's a race condition, so the results may vary.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - given that any `DownloadFileAsync` on `WebClient` is `void` returning, it would be impressive indeed to "await" on it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ah. Microsoft's dodgy naming convention strikes again. But the point remains - the `WebClient` object will potentially be disposed before the download is complete, and who knows what effect that would have on any attached event handlers...

Comment: So my recommendation is to change the call to use [`DownloadFileTaskAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfiletaskasync?view=net-6.0) and `await` it (which would also mean changing the `DownloadFile()` method to `public async Task DownloadFile()` along with all the knock-on changes that entails.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson i tried it and changed all the places but in the designer cs file code on the button i'm getting error : this.btnStartDownload.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnStartDownload_Click); the error is : has the wrong ruten type.  in form1 i changed the button click event to async Task and since then i'm getting the error in the designer code.

Comment: As you've discovered, click handlers have to be void - and this is one of the few cases where you're allowed to use an `async void` rather than an `async Task` method. So to fix this, change the declaration of the button handler to be `async void`.